# Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica Warning in pixReadMemPng

Tags: python-3.x, libpng, python-tesseract, libtiff, leptonica

I am trying to convert PNG image file to text using pytesseract. It is giving me the below error.
TesseractError: (1, 'Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica Warning in pixReadMemPng: work-around: writing to a temp file 
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.4.3 but running with 1.5.14 Error in pixReadStreamPng: png_ptr not made Error in pixReadMemPng: pix not read Error in pixReadMem: png: no pix returned Error during processing.')

When i do tesseract -v
tesseract 3.05.00dev
 leptonica-1.72
  libjpeg 9 : libpng 1.5.14 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.5 : libopenjp2 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem, and I can't find the answer on the internet.

But I try to download the **tesseract-ocr** and install it, then:

1. set environment variable, `TESSDATA_PREFIX:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata"`
2. add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR` to the path variable.
3. edit `pytesseract.py` in Line 35, `tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'`

When I call `pytesseract.image_to_string(img)` in anaconda prompt, it return a string. My Environment：

- pytesseract 0.2.6
- pillow 5.2.0
- tesseract 4.00.00alpha

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem:

In my pc tesseract engine version was 3.0.

when I installed tesseract engine of version 5.0 or greater and used its path as

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
```

[Tesseract download link](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)